# How to open Powershell Console Window from Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am writing a script to use multiple plink (PuTTY) sessions as a Windows version of clusterssh.  I am stuck however because I want to open multiple Powershell windows from powershell.  When I type the command for powershell, it opens a new session.  This is similar to typing bash in bash. I want multiple physical windows opening.

I tried -windowstyle as well as the other args to no avail.  I was wondering if there is a way you know of.  I really appreciate your help.  I looked and didn't find anything already here.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This will do it:

```
Invoke-Item C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

Comment: This sets the CWD of the new process to `C:\WINDOWS\system32` at least it does on my machine.

Comment: If anyone reads this, check out the answer with more up-votes at the bottom ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15668965/2430414))

Answer (score 203):

This will open a new window.

Either:

```
start-process powershell
```

Or:

```
start powershell
```

Comment: Even simpler is `start powershell`

Comment: Both of these commands preserve CWD of the old terminal! Good to know!

Comment: Possible to set the start directory via `-WorkingDirectory` directly.

Comment: `saps powershell` is even shorter to type

Comment: Odd thing - I'd changed the Powershell background colour a long time ago (well before opening the first Powershell window today!). When I opened a new window with this command, it had the original default colour.

Comment: For PowerShell Core: `Start-Process pwsh`

Answer (score 35):

if you are trying to open a new window and launch a new script:

```
start powershell {.\scriptInNewPSWindow.ps1}
```

Comment: Works great when you need to kick off a series of processes (i.e. npm).  There might be a better way, but as a developer that needs to get working quickly, this is great!

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

`` $argList = "-file `"$Location\script.ps1`""
Start-Process powershell -argumentlist $argList ``

(The backticks are necessary. This can be copied outright.) Variables can be used in the "-file" parameter (such as one set at the beginning of the script to reflect the location of the file) and spaces can appear in the variable due to the backticks.

**Edited** to use a two-line solution (the "$argList" variable) because PowerShell can mangle things otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

To start Powershell 6 from a PS console `start pwsh` might do the trick.
It starts in the same folder.

(I haven't delved into it but I guess PS6's pwsh.exe has to be in the path for it to work.)

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer using [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal) rather than the native PowerShell terminal, you can use this instead:

```bash
start-process wt
```

If you need to run with admin privilege, use:

```bash
start-process wt -verb runas
```