# Open a powershell window from an existing powershell window, and keep it open after running code

Tags: powershell

I can open a powershell window from an existing one and provide it code to run [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48940428/5783745)

But I can't get the second window to stay open once the code has run

Here's what I want to run in the first powershell window, and I would like the powershell window that opens to stay open after running the code (currently, it closes immediately)

```
start powershell { ECHO "hi" }
```

#### Note

I tried some suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739322/how-to-keep-the-shell-window-open-after-running-a-powershell-script) but not having any luck

Also, I got a fix (of sorts) using something like `start powershell { ECHO "hi"; TIMEOUT 20 }` but that's not going to keep the window permanently open

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
PowerShell -Command {Write-Host "Test" } -NoExit
```

from [about Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/About/about_PowerShell_exe?view=powershell-5.1). To start the Powershell in a new window you can use:

```
start-process  powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-noExit", "-command","Write-host 'TEST'; Write-Host 'Test2'"
```

Important `-Command` must be the last parameter ([about Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/About/about_PowerShell_exe?view=powershell-5.1)):

> When the value of Command is a string, Command must be the last parameter specified because any characters typed after the command are interpreted as the command arguments.

Answer (score 3):

**Generally:**

If you pass a *command* (`-Command`) or *script file* (`-File`) to execute to PowerShell's CLI (`powershell.exe` in *Windows PowerShell*, `pwsh.exe` in *PowerShell [Core] v6+*), PowerShell by default executes the command / script and then *exits*.

**With a command or script specified for execution, you need to add the `-NoExit` switch if you want the new session to remain open.**

Caveat: (Unless you call *directly* from within PowerShell with a *script block*), a *positional* argument - i.e., one neither preceded by `-Command` nor `-File` - is implicitly bound to:

- `-Command` in Windows PowerShell
- `-File` in PowerShell [Core] v6+.

Therefore, it's advisable to use the target parameter name explicitly.

---

**With [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Start-Process)** (whose built-in alias on Windows - but not on Unix - is `start`):

Note: The **primary use of `Start-Process` is to launch an independent process *asynchronously* in a *new window***. However, the latter isn't supported on Unix-like platforms, where `Start-Process`'s utility is therefore limited.

`start powershell { ECHO "hi" }` happens to work from PowerShell (except that the window closes right after executing the command), but it's important to note that you cannot actually pass *script blocks* to `Start-Process`, only *strings*.

`Start-Process` accepts an executable name (implied `-FilePath` parameter), and an *array* of *string* arguments (implied `-ArgumentList` / `-Args` parameter).

If you pass a *script block* (`{ ... }`), it is automatically *stringified*, meaning that its *literal string contents* are used (stripped of the `{` and `}`) as the (only) `-ArgumentList` string value.

Thus, bypassing the unnecessary script-block creation, your command - with `-NoExit` applied as desired - should be (with explicitly named parameters; note that `-Command` and its argument must come *last*):

```
Start-Process -FilePath powershell -ArgumentList '-NoExit -Command ECHO "hi"'
```

**Note**:

- While passing arguments *individually*, as an *array* to `-ArgumentList` is arguably conceptually cleaner, it is actually **better to pass all arguments as a *single* string, using embedded quoting as necessary**, due to a longstanding bug - see [GitHub issue #5576](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576).
- **Trying to open an interactive shell in a new window *as a different user*, via the `-Credential` parameter, is broken** up to at least PowerShell 7.1, resulting in keyboard input getting blocked both in the new window and in the caller's window - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60683080/45375) for a **workaround with `runas.exe`** and [GitHub issue #12129](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12129).

Comment: @Benni: Please see my update (at the bottom). If that's not your scenario, I have no explanation, I'm afraid.